# Spark Streaming - Netcat messages are not received in Spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

i am trying to test spark streaming. i have stand alone cloudera quickstart vm. started the spark-shell with the following command:

```
spark-shell --master yarn-client --conf spark.ui.port=23123
```

In the spark-shell i have executed the following statements:

```
sc.stop()
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Streaming")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf,org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds(10))
val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost",44444)
lines.print
```

In another terminal started the netcat service with the following command:

```
nc -lk 44444
```

In the spark-shell started the streaming context

```
ssc.start()
```

till now everything is fine. But, whatever the messages typed in the Netcat service are not received in Spark streaming.don't know where it is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `spark-shell --master local[2] --conf spark.ui.port=23123` to see if it works.

If it works, then in your script, there is only one executor working, which is receiving message, but no executor is processing message.

Comment: It worked. Thank you. what is the reason. your explanation will go long way my friend.

Comment: In your script，`spark-shell --master yarn-client --conf spark.ui.port=23123`, you should specify the --num-executors N where N should be >=2, it is because, for your code to work,  there  should be at least 2 executors, one for receiving message, the other is used to process message(lines.print in your case)

Comment: Thank you. Have a nice day.